# IE 8 defaultView equivalent

Tags: javascript

I need from document object or from a DOM element (i.e. a DIV) to know
which is its window object.

In Firefox I can do:

```
document.documentElement.ownerDocument.defaultView
```

but obviously in that AWFUL browser that statement not work!!!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[parentWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534331%28VS.85%29.aspx). So:

```
var doc = el.ownerDocument;
var win = ('defaultView' in doc) ? doc.defaultView : doc.parentWindow;
```

Comment: `var win= (doc.defaultView : doc.parentWindow);`

Answer (score 3):

```
var win = doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow;
```

should do the trick too.