# How to get window containing given element in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, window

Lets assume that I have given some DOM element, eg. paragraph referenced by variable `p`. To get window in which `p` is contained I can use following code:
`p.ownerDocument.defaultView`, but this doesn't work in IE prior to version 9. How can I in general find parent window of given element, even if that element is inside Iframe (In that case it should be frame window, not the top window)?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297217/ie-8-defaultview-equivalent

Comment: This is the answer, I think my question is duplicate.