# execScript try/catch oddity in IE 8

Tags: javascript

I am using execScript within a try/catch  block to execute a piece of stringified JavaScript. If the string has a javascript error within execScript will return the following error within the catch block in IE 8 on a subsequent reload of the page:

'Error: Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101.'

Are there any other ways of globally evaluating javascript in IE 8 which will not throw a generic error like the one above. I know that using eval will not work since it does not evaluate the javascript in the global context.

Below is some setup as to what my code looks like, fn is the string that is to be evaluated:

```
// fn is defined somewhere above this code

function globalEvaluation() {
    if(document.defaultView) {
       document.defaultView.eval.call(undefined, fn);
    } else if (document.parentWindow) {
        document.parentWindow.execScript(fn);
    } 
}

return function() {
    try {
         globalEvaluation();
    } catch(e) {
       // do some error handling
       // in IE 8 I get the 80020101 error
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this error occur when IE's script engine encounters invalid javascript (my recent example: trying to call invalid javascript or a nonexistent function directly through SHDocVw.dll via COM).  So I interpret that error message as saying that IE8 just plain thinks that you're feeding it something invalid and will choke no matter what.

Could this be the issue? [IE 8 defaultView equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297217/ie-8-defaultview-equivalent) Although `document.defaultView.eval.call` still seems to work fine for me in IE9.

My guess would be that there's a bug in `fn`, maybe something is still out of scope? If you pass it something that it considers invalid, I believe it's always going to throw that unhelpful error. Is `fn` doing any null-checking/error handling of its own?